# Using IDL on Windows command line

Tags: windows, cmd, idl-programming-language

I am trying to start an IDL programme from the Windows command line.
Lets say I have the following programme:

```
PRO hello  
print, "Hello, I am a IDL script!"  
a=bytarr(100,200)  
outname='g:\testimage.tif'  
WRITE_TIFF, outname, a  
END
```

I want to execute this programme using IDL -e .RUN from the command line as following:

```
C:\Users\lein_pa>idl -e ".RUN G:/05_Software/01_IDL/IDLWorkspace/Default/hello.pro"  
IDL Version 8.2, Microsoft Windows (Win32 x86_64 m64). (c) 2012, Exelis Visual Information Solutions, Inc.  
Installation number: xxxxx.  
Licensed for use by: xxx  

% Compiled module:HELLO.  
C:\Users\lein_pa>
```

As you can see HELLO.pro will be compiled, but no message "Hello, I am a IDL script!" appears on the shell and also testimage.tif is not written to the disk. When I start this programme from the IDL IDE everything works fine.

Can please someone help me? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How to get idl ? , It says idl command is not recognized

Answer (score 1):

You could keep the file with the same name, but change it to a batch-like file by commenting out the `PRO hello` and `END` since everything in your routine could just as easily be run from the command line.

Then to start everything, try:

```
C:\Users\lein_pa>idl -e G:/05_Software/01_IDL/IDLWorkspace/Default/hello.pro
```

On unix-based systems, this would start IDL and immediately run the batch file hello.pro.  If you need the double quotes for a Windows based machine, then add those accordingly.

Keep in mind, if you make this routine more complicated but keep it as a batch file, then be careful with loops as you will need to use `$` and `& $` at the end of lines to include them in loops.  I am quite certain that one could run actual programs/functions on startup, but it's just as easy to type in the function name after startup if it's necessary.  Typically one wants to use a startup batch routine to set personal preferences/defaults that you wish to use or commonly use when in IDL.

Comment: That's a good idea, thanks a lot. But hello.pro of course is only a simple example programme. I want to call already exisiting very complex programmes from the command line, that cannot be changed in their structure or codings.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to have a number of routines run when you first start IDL or that you want to be able to run IDL routines from outside of IDL on a command line?  The former is very easy, just call them from inside a simple bash routine like your hello.pro or even from the command line once in IDL.  The latter is possible, but may be a little trickier.  Have you looked at: [Command-line Options for IDL Startup](http://www.exelisvis.com/docs/command_line_options_for.html) or [Executing SAVE Files](http://www.exelisvis.com/docs/Executing_SAVE_Files.html) to see if those options work?

Comment: Thanks for the links - they helped me to figure out the mistake! I realized that the problem was a small difference in the idl call. While unix based systems work with idl, windows virtual machines work with idlrt to run programmes from the command line.